# How to fully load a website in a background tab in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser, web, tabs, background

How can one ensure a website gets fully loaded when the site is opened in a Firefox background tab?

For example, the [*COVID-19 Dashboard by the Center for Systems Science and Engineering (CSSE) at Johns Hopkins University (JHU)*](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/dashboards/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6) takes a fairly long time to load, so I usually load it in background tab.  Yet, even after waiting a minute or two, if I bring the background tab with that site to the foreground, much of the site doesn't begin to load until the tab is in the foreground.

I've had similar experiences when trying to save pages to the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/) in background tabs.  As long as the tab is in the foreground, the operation progresses.  Yet, when saving a web page to the Wayback Machine in a background tab, it will never complete, even after letting it sit for hours.

How can one make processing of background tabs similar to that of foreground tabs in Firefox?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to disable true lazy loading for Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/1605771/is-there-any-way-to-disable-true-lazy-loading-for-firefox)

Comment: @spikey_richie Thanks.  Isn't what's described in that question just for images that are lazy loaded?

Comment: I think it's the whole page. You could try setting the flag, and see if the desired outcome is reached.

Comment: @spikey_richie Thanks. I'll give it a try.  But as the name of the flag has the word "image" right in it, I think the odds of it working aren't too great. ;)

Comment: In which case you can set the radio button that asks if this (the link I shared) answers your question, to no.

Comment: @spikey_richie Had to get some sleep...  Now that I'm awake, I gave that pref a try.  Unfortunately, it didn't help.  No harm in trying it though. :)  I marked the link as "doesn't answer question", but I appreciate you finding that link.  Thanks.

Comment: No problems, I'll keep looking around for a different fix.